# Button click event not firing on server

Tags: c#, button, cookies, click, server

Have a little problem with my button click event. It's working properly on my localhost when I run my visual studio debugging, but when I upload files on server this button click event works just in a half. It stoppes on http cookie line. Its inserting everything to database, but after this and before http cookie - it stoppes and not going to continue. Where can be a problem? I'm fighting with this issue for 8 hours now...

```
string query = "INSERT INTO CMS_ORDERS_BUYERS (BUYER_ID, BUYER_DATE, BUYER_NAME, BUYER_SURNAME, BUYER_ADRESS, BUYER_CITY, BUYER_POSTCODE, BUYER_MAIL, BUYER_PHONE, BUYER_DELIVERY, BUYER_VAT, BUYER_GUID, CLIENT_ID, BUYER_NIP, BUYER_COMPANY, BUYER_CODE) VALUES (@ID, @DATE, @NAME, @SURNAME, @ADRESS, @CITY, @POSTCODE, @MAIL, @PHONE, @DELIVERY, @VAT, @GUID, @CLIENT_ID, @NIP, @COMPANY, @CODE)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Imię.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SURNAME", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Nazwisko.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ADRESS", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Adres.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CITY", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Miejscowość.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@POSTCODE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = KodPocztowy.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MAIL", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Email.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PHONE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Telefon.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DELIVERY", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VAT", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = VAT;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request.Cookies["GUID"].Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CLIENT_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NIP", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = NIP.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Company.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODE", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rabat.Text;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                HttpCookie guidCookie = Request.Cookies["GUID"];
                guidCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
                guidCookie.Value = null;
                Response.Cookies.Add(guidCookie);

                string listaProduktow = "";
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    listaProduktow += row.Cells[2].Text + "x " + row.Cells[1].Text + ", ";
                }

                string rodzajPrzesylki = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Substring(0, DropDownList1.SelectedValue.IndexOf("-"));

                string kwotaRazem = GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text.Substring(0, GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text.IndexOf(" "));

                string cenaPrzesylki = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Substring(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.IndexOf("-") + 1);

                string z24_id_sprzedawcy = "*****";
                string z24_nazwa = "****** " + id.ToString();
                string z24_crc = "*******";
                string z24_return_url = "*********/koszyk.aspx?done";
                decimal znizka = 1 - Convert.ToDecimal(znizkaZBazy) / 100;
                decimal kwotaZamowienie = Convert.ToDecimal(kwotaRazem);
                decimal kwotaPrzesylka = Convert.ToDecimal(cenaPrzesylki.Substring(0, cenaPrzesylki.IndexOf("P")));
                decimal z24_kwota_decimal = ((znizka * kwotaZamowienie) + kwotaPrzesylka) * 100;
                string z24_kwota = Convert.ToInt32(z24_kwota_decimal).ToString();

                string przelewy24URL = "https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php?z24_id_sprzedawcy=" + z24_id_sprzedawcy + "&z24_nazwa=" + z24_nazwa + "&z24_crc=" + z24_crc + "&z24_kwota=" + z24_kwota + "&z24_return_url=" + z24_return_url + "";

                string body = PopulateBody(id.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), Imię.Text, Nazwisko.Text, Adres.Text, KodPocztowy.Text, Miejscowość.Text, Telefon.Text, Email.Text, listaProduktow, rodzajPrzesylki, (znizka * kwotaZamowienie).ToString("0.00"), cenaPrzesylki, NIP.Text, Company.Text);
                SendHtmlFormattedEmail(Email.Text, "Zamówienie - Naturalna Wytwórnia Piękna", body);

                Response.Redirect(przelewy24URL);
```

Comment: can you warp it with try/catch and see what's the exception?

Comment: It's not even throwing the exception.

Comment: if you place a breaking point in the catch statement - the debugger does not stop there?

Comment: No, the problem is that everything is working locally - on my localhost. It's not working on the server and I don't know why... Everything else is working on the server, just not that button click event.

Comment: can you log the exception on the server? - also - it may caused if the coockie does not exist in the request

Comment: But its there, because I see it's saving it into db in my admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that not allow my script to work properly was update panel in my aspx file. I have a asyncpostback trigger connected to my button click event, but I forgot that I moved it outside the update panel, so I repaired my updatepanel by deleting trigger and it turned out that I need to change my mailing port from 587 to 25 inside my web.config. Now everything is working fine!